# It's possible to clone WebView and WebEngine in JavaFX?

Tags: webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

Is possible to clone WebView and WebEngine in JavaFX ? If is possible, please how?

Comment: You might be able to .get all of the properties of the original node and then set the properties of another node to the properties of the original but that would probably be quiet inefficient

Answer (score -1):

No, JavaFX does not support cloning nodes.